# SpagoBI Chart rendering engine in custom webapp

Tags: spagobi

I'm struggling to have a chart correctly rendered in an html page.

In SpagoBI webapp, I log in as "biuser", then go to "document" menu, then take the 1st chart that is already here ("Char Grouped Bar"). In the Spago webapp, I can see the chart, as it is rendered through ExtJS. 
Then I want to display this chart in an html page, to put in my own webapp. I acheive this with the Spago Javascript SDK, via the `injectDocument` method.

My code is:

```
Sbi.sdk.api.injectDocument({
    documentLabel: 'Char Grouped Bar'
    , executionRole: '/spagobi/user'
    , parameters: {warehouse_id: 19}
    , displayToolbar: false
    , displaySliders: false
    , target: 'targetDiv'
    , height: '500px'
    , width: '800px'
    , iframe: {
        style: 'border: 0px;'
    }
});
```

This does not work, as the SDK wants to render the chart via the HighCharts library, and I do not have this library (and do not want to).

=> I can see no documentation about this, so, how can I render the chart via ExtJS, as in the SpagoBI admin webapp?

Thanks!

Comment: I am facing similar problems. But in my case cockpit is getting displayed but  `parameters` is not working.. parameters are getting ignored..I am using `Sbi.sdk.api.getDocumentUrl`.... Did you came across such situation?